# Can I style the alt attribute of an image tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, alt

I'm using this Jquery function so show a caption above images using the associated alt tag in the html. I'd like to be able to style the text that shows and was wondering if there is a way to do this. Here is the code I'm using.

```
$(function () {
    var show = false;
    $(".thumb").mouseenter(function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        var $d = $("<div>");
        $d.addClass("desc").text($t.attr("alt")).css({
            width: $t.width(),
            height: $t.height() - 20,
            top: $t.position().top
        });
        $t.after($d).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
        $d.mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("fast", 0, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            }).siblings("img.thumb").fadeTo("fast", 1.3);
        });
    });
    $('#caption-toggle').click(function() {
        if (!show) $('.thumb').trigger('mouseenter');
        else {
            $('.thumb ~ div').fadeOut("fast", 0, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            }).siblings("img.thumb").fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
        }   
        show = !show;
    });
});
```

Most people have answered no to similar questions on this site, but I wanted to ask for myself to make sure whether this is possible or not. Cheers!

Comment: But you're already styling it! What is the problem with styling it even more? By the way, I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DFp6/), but is it really supposed to act like that? I mean, it keeps adding more and more text to the page if you wave your mouse over the image.

Comment: I believe he does not know what the code pasted here does

Comment: Apologies for not being specific. The specific styling I was looking for is the position of the text. I'm able to center the text by styling the div that wraps the img tag but I'm unable to move it to the middle of the image vertically. Is this possible through CSS or Jquery?

Comment: the `alt` attribute has been advocated mainly to serve as a stand-in in case the image cannot be loaded and to aid visually impaired users and the tools (eg. screen readers) they are using to deal with image content. imho this suggests _not_ to style the `alt` attribute contents at all even if it was technically possible. using it as a source for text to be used somewhere else appears perfectly acceptable, however.

Comment: svillamayor, you are absolutely correct. I'm have no idea how this function works but I'm doing by best to learn. Everyone's got to start somewhere. Mr Lister, you don't need to doubt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style alt text color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044611/how-to-style-alt-text-color)

Comment: There are several existing questions on styling `alt` attributes, the basic answer being “No”. Adding jQuery to this does not change the facts. Please do not create duplicates of existing questions; instead, contribute to improving their answers, if possible, or just accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find out how the function works, that will save you lots of time in the future.
I see you've got more questions about the very same function, which all wouldn't have been necessary if you already knew how it worked.

(Sorry, in case you didn't realise, that was tongue in cheek. Because the same thing is true for every other question here on StackOverflow!)

Anyway, the trick is to make the outer div `position:relative` so that the inner divs are positioned in the same spot. Then all you need to do is put them in the middle, for instance by setting the `line-height` to the same value as the height of the image. And with absolute positioning, you won't need the `z-index`.

Resulting fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CTQvN/172/)

Comment: Thank you Mr Lister. I will take your advice into careful consideration in the future. Apologies for any repeated elements to my question, though I do appreciate the time you took to respond to my question. Cheers!