# Custom alternative text of the unload the image

Tags: html, css

I have image tag

If the user has disabled the download of pictures or for some reason they did not load properly, then place icons should appear comfortable text, like this: [image: Example]

And yet, there may be an image of circles, transparent in the middle, it means that simply the text under the picture will not post.

What there are ways of making such alternative text - NOT using JS,it test task and it says there is solution wothout JS ?

Property 'alt' - unusable because I must set text with color (Attached image)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `alt` attribute to your text and style it using CSS:

```
<img id="myImage" src="" alt="Some text" />
```

CSS:

```
#myImage {
    color: red;
}
```

More information: [How to style alt text color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044611/how-to-style-alt-text-color/9045876#9045876)

Answer (score 0):

You can style the alt text displayed on a broken image. Use the `color:` style on either the image itself or on the image's container (the image will inherit the color).

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/utcTQ/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="notarealimg.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    color: red;
}

img { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: but how can I doing like in my image. Text not all in one color

Comment: @GeraySuinov, using only CSS I do not believe it's possible. Normally you could wrap each letter in a different span and add or remove colors that way, but this text is generated via an attribute, so it gets a color applied to text and that's all. Also, there isn't a CSS selector that would allow you to get the effect you're looking for [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)